# Express.js Error in rendering html files that are not named index

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

It doesn't give any sort of error when I use index.html but whenever I use any other name, it throws error. This is my code:-

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express(); 

app.use(express.static('Images'));  //It tells node that Images folder is the root folder

//app.set('view engine','html');

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
   res.render("home");
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server listening to PORT:3000");
});
```

**And here is the Error**

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at E:\NewExp\App.js:9:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\NewExp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

**Why am I getting this error whenever I use any other name than index?**

Comment: Isn't `render` for actually rendering templates (Pug, handlebars, etc)? You don't need to render a template if you just want to send a static HTML file

Comment: @JeremyThille Then what should I do?

Comment: [res.sendFile()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) I guess

Comment: @JeremyThille It's not working. Error:- Path must is absolute or relative

Comment: ... so provide an absolute or relative path :)

Comment: The **error stack** is your friend, my friend. `no default engine was specified` means 1) you must specify a default engine and 2) you must specify the `views` directory you want express to use to render your views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I assume you want to use `html` files (or extensions) as a default engine for express.

From [express docs:](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html)

> Use the app.engine(ext, callback) method to create your own template engine. ext refers to the file extension, and callback is the template engine function, which accepts the following items as parameters: the location of the file, the options object, and the callback function.

Use case:

```
var fs = require('fs')

app.engine('html', function (filePath, options, callback) {
  fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, content) {
    if (err) return callback(err)
    // simple template engine
    var rendered = content.toString()
     .replace('#title#', '<title>' + options.title + '</title>')
     .replace('#message#', '<h1>' + options.message + '</h1>')
    return callback(null, rendered)
 })
})

app.set('views', './views')    // specify the views directory
app.set('view engine', 'html') // register the template engine
```

And render like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!' })
})
```